# How to get the percentage of occurrence of a value in a column into a new column, in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2], 'val':[1,1,1,0]})
```

I would like to create a new column, which will have the percentage of `val == 1` by `id`

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2], 'val':[1,1,1,0], 'percentage':[1,1,0.5,0.5})
```

Any ideas how I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only `0,1` values you can use `mean` with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new column:

```
foo['percentage'] = foo.groupby('id')['val'].transform('mean')
print (foo)
   id  val  percentage
0   1    1         1.0
1   1    1         1.0
2   2    1         0.5
3   2    0         0.5
```

If any values in `val` is necessary first compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
foo['percentage'] = foo['val'].eq(1).groupby(foo['id']).transform('mean')
```